# SSL Certificate fails for CA certificate in mosquitto 1.2.1/1.2.2

Tags: ssl, certificate, mqtt, mosquitto

While trying to upgrade from mosquitto 1.1.3 to 1.2.1/1.2.1. I am getting this error while trying to subscribe to an event.

> mosquitto_sub -h 192.168.255.2 -p 8883 -v -t "test" --cafile /etc/certs/rootCA/ca.root.crt –d
>
> OpenSSL Error: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

The same CA certificate is working fine with 1.1.3 version.

Is there any problem with the openssl version ? 
I have the version 1.0.0.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `commonName` in your certificate does not match the hostname (in this case the IP address) you are connecting to. 1.1.3 did not verify this, and so was vulnerable to your server being impersonated.

You should either fix your `commonName` to match the hostname you are using, or better use the `subjectAltName` certificate extension to provide your hostname/IP address. `subjectAltName` allows you to specify any number of hostnames and IP addresses in a certificate. [Mqttitude](http://mqttitude.org/) has an example of how to generate certificates: https://github.com/binarybucks/mqttitude/blob/master/tools/TLS/generate-CA.sh

I believe that using an IP address as the commonName is frowned upon.

As a final option, you can also use the `--insecure` options for mosquitto_pub/sub, or set `tls_insecure` if you are using a bridge. As these options suggest, doing so will reduce the security of your system.

Comment: In my case the server certificate does have the IP address for common names.                                                                      Subject: C=ABC, ST=DEF, O=GHI , OU=XYZ, CN=192.168.255.130, CN=192.168.255.2                                                     But the CA certificate doesnt have any valid hostname/IP address. Does the CN of CA certificate also contain valid IP ?

Comment: Mosquitto doesn't support multiple CN per certificate. There is some argument about which CN should be validated. Mosquitto uses the openssl default of the first CN. If you wish to have multiple hostnames in a certificate, use subjectAltName.